# Change the color of tab icon for selected, unselected and pressed - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I have set foreground color grey in unselected, blue in selected and pressed in theme and the UIID name is "Tab". The text in the tab works fine but the fontImage is always gray whether selected, unselected or pressed. I've used UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab") in style of fontIMage.createMaterial. Why doesn't the icon of tabs change as its text?

```
Style iconStyle = UIManager.getInstance().getComponentStyle("Tab");

Image calendarIcon2 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_UPDATE, iconStyle, 4);
Image calendarIcon3 = FontImage.createMaterial(FontImage.MATERIAL_WHATSHOT, iconStyle, 4);

Tabs tabs = new Tabs(Component.BOTTOM);
tabs.addTab("Home", calendarIcon2, new Container());
tabs.addTab("Servicing", calendarIcon3, new Container());
tabs.addTab("History", calendarIcon, new Container());
tabs.addTab("Quick Booking", calendarIcon1, new Container());

add(BorderLayout.CENTER, tabs);
```

In the following image of tabs, why does the color of the icon of selected tab gray but not blue as the text of the tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You used a fixed image, the colors of an image won't change dynamically as the tabs aren't aware of `FontImage`.

There are two approaches for this. You can use the newer material design specific `addTab` API:

```
addTab(String title, char materialIcon, float iconSize, Component component)
```

Alternatively you can create icons in the right colors with the font image and set them explicitly using:

```
setTabSelectedIcon(Component tab, Image icon)
```

Comment: Tried the first one but doesn't work... tabs.addTab("Home", FontImage.MATERIAL_HOME, 4, homeContainer);

Comment: I see a bug here. We picked selected instead of pressed style, it should be fixed in the next update